# I keep getting the same incorrect result in a differential equation and I don't know what I'm missing

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So I've got the following differential equation, and this is how I'm trying to solve it.

$$x^2 + y^2 - 2xyy' = 0$$
$$y' = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2xy}$$

Since it's a homogenous differential equation, I used $y=ux$, and got this:
$$u' = \frac{1-u^2}{2ux} $$ 
$$\int \frac {2u\ du}{1-u^2} = \int \frac{dx}{x}$$

Using $1-u^2=t$ and $2u du = -dt $ I got the following:

$$\int-\frac{dt}{t} = \int\frac{dx}{x} \\
-\ln{t} = \ln{x} + c \\
1-u^2 = x+e^c \\
y^2 + x^2 = x^2(x + e^c) $$

Yet, for some reason, the given solution is specifically this:

$$y^2 + x^2 = xc$$

Am I applying the method for solving these wrong or something? I'm lost. Thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you forgot $u$ in $y' = (u x)' = u' + u$

Comment: @PavelIevlev Isn't this correct?:

$y' = (ux)' = u'x + ux' = xdu/dx + udx/dx = u'x + u$

Comment: Sorry. Everything's fine there. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got off to a great start! The following was all fine:

$$x^2 + y^2 - 2xyy' = 0$$
$$y' = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2xy}$$
$$u' = \frac{1-u^2}{2ux}$$
$$\int \frac {2u\ du}{1-u^2} = \int \frac{dx}{x}$$
$$\int-\frac{dt}{t} = \int\frac{dx}{x}$$
$$-\ln{t} = \ln{x} + c$$

After that, though, you went off the rails. From there you *should* have:

$$-\ln(1-u^2) = \ln(x)+c$$
$$\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-u^2}\right)=\ln\left(e^cx\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{1-u^2}=e^cx$$
$$\frac{x^2}{x^2-u^2x^2}=e^cx$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2-y^2}=\frac{e^c}x$$
$$x^2-y^2=e^{-c}x$$
$$y^2=x^2-e^{-c}x$$
$$y^2=x^2+Cx$$

Answer (score 3):

Another approach will be:

$$ \frac{d(y^2)}{dx}-\frac{y^2}{x} =x$$

which is a linear equation with integration factor $e^{-\ln x}=1/x$. The solution is:

$$y^2 \frac{1}{x} = \int dx = x+C$$

The solution should be $$y^2 = x^2+ cx$$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

$-\ln (1 + u^2) = \ln x + \mathrm{const} \Rightarrow 1 + u^2 = \frac{C}{x},$

because $$-\ln x = \ln \frac{1}{x}.$$